# Axios GET request (from backend) with object as parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, http, axios

I'm having a lot of trouble using `axios` to send requests to this API, which accepts parameters in an object fashion:

`GET https://api.osrsbox.com/items?where={ "name": "Abyssal whip", "duplicate": false }`

The main problem is that `axios` automatically encodes the string. Searching for solutions in StackOverflow, i've came to this:

```js
    const item = "Abyssal Whip"

    const config = {
        paramsSerializer: (params) => {
            return querystring.stringify(params, { arrayFormat: 'brackets' });
        },
        params: {
            where : {
                name: item,
                duplicate: false
            }
        }
    }

    axios.get("https://api.osrsbox.com/items", config).then( (resp) => {
        [...]
    })
```

This results in the following request:

`https://api.osrsbox.com/items?where=%7B%22name%22:%22Abyssal%20Whip%22,%22duplicate%22:false%7D`

I would like to know what am i doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm making requests from a Node.js environment/server.

Comment: Just append the stringified search object directly to the url: https://jsfiddle.net/5eygf3dL/

Comment: Your example doesn't uses axios. I am making this request from a node server instead of  front-end page. However, i tried to use your example and no success.

Comment: Ah ok, here's an axios version: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/0gp62o8e/

Comment: @ChrisG your help is very valuable, however this is the URL axios is requesting: `https://api.osrsbox.com/items?where=%7B%22name%22:%22Abyssal%20Whip%22,%22duplicate%22:false%7D`. I am making this request from a node.js server, do you think this has something to do with?

Comment: This works fine for me on node: https://pastebin.com/raw/mnUrFTJX

Comment: Omg, it didn't work either. I'm almost giving up this project. Does it need any axios configuration? I literally copy/pasted your code and didn't work.

Comment: No, are you getting any error messages? What happens when you run my code?

Comment: @ChrisG it doesn't get any errors, but the URL characters are escaped, and then it returns an empty array for the items. I need the `{` and `}` characters to avoid being sent as `%7B` and `%7D`

Comment: I'm running it on Windows using node 12.10 and it works fine. If it returns an empty array for the items it sounds like the request went through though? Note that `"Abyssal Whip"` indeed returns `[]` but `"Abyssal whip"` works fine. Maybe *this* was the problem all along?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a really weird format that your API accepts. But I suppose it's what you've got to work with...

It looks to me like you might be successful by changing the relevant part of your code to:

```
where: JSON.stringify({
    name: item,
    duplicate: false
})
```

(I hope the spaces in your example request aren't required, if they are then this won't work)

Comment: Hello, your suggestion is computed by `axios` this way: `https://api.osrsbox.com/items?where=%7B%22name%22%3A%22Abyssal%20Whip%22%2C%22duplicate%22%3Afalse%7D`. I agree with you, this is a bad design for API but i don't have control over it.

Comment: oh yes, it will be, because that's how curly braces and quotes (etc) are URL-encoded. I would assume your API has to accept it in this form, because a GET request is all about what's in the URL. Have you tested whether the request actually works?

Comment: It doesn't work... the API doens't accept the escaped characters. Really bad designed API.

Comment: huh - well in that case I don't know how anyone or anything ever calls this API

Comment: although of course one final thing to try is to call [decodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) - so `where: decodeURI(JSON.stringify({...})`. If this works I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use npm package "qs"

1. npm i qs
2. make a object which has all your request body params eg -

const requestBody = {

....... ;

}

3. now while making Axios request -

   Axios.get("https://api.osrsbox.com/items", qs.stringyfy(requestBody),        config)
   .then(res => console.log(res)
   .catch(err => console.log(err))

Comment: Can you provide the filled example of requestBody? I am getting some errors with: `const requestBody = { where: { name: item, duplicate: false } }`

Comment: does your api's body have a key name as "params" ?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Everything is passed as an object like mentioned.

Comment: well , that's weird , the only thing i can tell you now is to remove the return in your  paramsSerializer: (params) => {
             querystring.stringify(params, { arrayFormat: 'brackets' });
        },

Comment: because arrow function already returns something you don't need to specify the "return", try it maybe it works , otherwise wait for someone who can answer , I'll remove mine . thanks